# Accepting that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = +∞$ prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\delta}{\ln^\gamma n} = +\infty$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I have the following problem to prove.

> Let $\gamma, δ \in \mathbb{R}^\ast_+$ and 
>   $f\colon \mathbb{R}^\ast_+\to \mathbb{R}$
>   defined by $f(x) = \delta x − \gamma\ln x$.
>
> Accepting that $\lim_{x\to+\infty }f(x) = +\infty$ prove that
>   $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^\delta}{\ln^\gamma n}  = +\infty$.

The following substitution is true:
$$n^\delta=e^{\delta\ln n}$$

Any hint, suggestion or solution is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Is it $\ln_{\gamma}(n)$ or $\ln^{\gamma}(n)$, your title and question differ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider 
$$
e^{f(x)}=e^{\delta x-\gamma\ln x}.
$$
Choose $x=\ln n$, then
$$
e^{f(x)}=e^{\delta x-\gamma\ln x}=e^{\delta\ln n-\gamma\ln \ln n}=\frac{e^{\delta\ln n}}{e^{\gamma\ln \ln n}}=\frac{n^\delta}{(\ln n)^\gamma}.
$$
Since $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\ln n\rightarrow\infty$ and so you can relate what you have to $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{f(x)}$.

Answer (score 3):

So you must show that $g(n)\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{n^\delta}{(\ln n)^\gamma} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$, with $\delta,\gamma > 0$.

This is equivalent to showing that $\ln g(n) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$ (can you see why?).

But $\ln g(n) = \delta \ln n - \gamma\ln \ln n = f(\ln n)$. Use your hypothesis now.

Comment: @ClementC.  $(\log n)^\gamma \ne \gamma \log n$.  Perhaps the OP meant $\log(n^\gamma)=\gamma \log(n)$.

Comment: Yes, I was missing a log here, in both places. Silly mistake... Thanks! (Fixed)